# Can I have a custom View when using itemController in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a way I can have a custom view when doing `{{#each array itemController="something"}}` in Ember.js? Currently, the Ember inspector shows that Ember is using a "virtual" view.

For example, no alert ever happens for the following Handlebars:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model}}
      <li>
        {{name}}
        <ul>
          {{#each kids itemController="kid"}}
            <li>{{name}}? {{yelledName}}!</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
App.KidController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  yelledName: Ember.computed('name', function() {
    return this.get('name').toString().toUpperCase();
  })
});

App.KidView = Ember.View.extend({
  // THIS NEVER HAPPENS!
  test: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    alert('didInsertElement on ThingView');
  })
});
```

Here's a codepen with that code (not) working: http://cdpn.io/hveEA

It appears that Ember is *not* attempting to look up the View by its name like it might if it were a View from a Controller from a Route. Instead, it just renders a "virtual" view, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Ember Inspector Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with using this (Which allows you to use a `KidView`):

```
{{#each kid in kids}}
{{render 'kid' kid}}
{{/each}}
```

I don't see you using any model properties.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="kid">
    <li>{{name}}? {{yelledName}}!</li>
</script>
```

View:

```
App.KidView = Ember.View.extend({
  // THIS HAPPENS!
  test: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    alert('didInsertElement on ThingView');
  })
});
```

Full code sample:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8971543

Answer (score 1):

kidView would be used whenever you transition to a route with kid_id, something like this /kids/:kid_id, that's when KidView would be used. What you're expecting is not possible, unless you specify the view in the each loop:

```
{{#each kids itemController="kid"}}
  {{view App.KidView kid=this}}
{{/each}}
```

and in the view's template you access the 'kid' and display whatever you want.

Comment: btw, itemController will be used only to decorate your kid object, it won't instantiate a new App.KidView

Comment: So I'd then have to have a `'kid'` template instead of being able to do it inline in the `{{#each}}`?